# Django static files 404 not found

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, python-3.x

I have read all of the similar questions regarding this and still can't find an answer. I downloaded a template from HTML5 and all of the required CSS, JS and images but when I run the server I get:

```
**
Not Found: /erthreal/assets/js/main.js
[04/Aug/2018 12:02:40] "GET /erthreal/assets/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2126
[04/Aug/2018 12:02:40] "GET /erthreal/images/gallery/thumbs/06.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2159
[04/Aug/2018 12:02:40] "GET /erthreal/images/gallery/thumbs/07.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2159
**
```

I have the following written in my settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        'erthreal/erthreal/templates/'
    ],

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/',),
    'erthreal/static/erthreal',
]
```

In my index.html:

```
    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>personal</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "erthreal/assets/css/main.css" %}"/>
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="erthreal/assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
    </head>
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

def index(request):
    index = Index.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'erthreal/templates/index.html')
```

I have read through all of the documentation both on the django website and the howto folders (which are pretty much copies of each other), but cant find an answer on how to fix it. This is my folder layout:

```
      erthreal/
    static/
        erthreal/
            assets/
                CSS/
                fonts/
                js/
                sass/
            images/
    templates/
        erthreal/
          index.html
```

It will load the template just not the associated static file.

Comment: You've ran `collectstatic` right?

Comment: No, but when I do it gives me: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user1/virtualenvironment/mysite/static'

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't successfully ran `collectstatic` then your static folder didn't update; explaining why you're receiving the `Not Found` error.

Update the error in your structure `/home/user1/virtualenvironment/mysite/static`

Comment: I tried it a few different ways but I'm still getting the same error but now it renders the style sheet. when I do collect static it created a static folder under the mysite/ directory. Is that where it belongs?